# Ajax call to aspx page JQuery JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, json

I ‘m trying to make an Ajax call to an aspx page 
On the server side request comes as "object object" and I cannot serialize it getting “not a JSON primitive.. ” it works however when instead of json object I pass json string .... Problem is that on a client side I’m using a json object that I have to convert to string before sending. I tried using function JSONToString() from json.org but this throws an error when I add jquery library.
 Does anybody know how it should be done I would much appreciate any help.

add    "JQuery/jquery-1.3.2.js"

add    "js/json.js"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callAjax() {

    var myjson = { document: { manufacture: { item: ['Alfa Romeo']}} }     
        $.ajax({
            url: 'jsonresponse.aspx',
            type: 'POST',                
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: myjson.toJSONString(),  // throws an error in json libary //  return JSON.parse(this, filter); //.. Microsoft JScript compilation error: Syntax error
            //data: myjson, can't serialize on the server request comes as object object
            //data:{ document: { manufacture: { item: ['Alfa Romeo']}} }, works but I need something to convert object to a string as it is much bigger then the one in example 
            timeout: 1000000,
            dataType: "json",
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            },
            success: function(myResult) {
            //alert(myResult);              
            }
        });
    }
```

jsonresponse.aspx

```
    XmlDocument myxml = new XmlDocument();  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Page.Request.InputStream);

    string test;
    test = reader.ReadToEnd();

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    myxml = jss.Deserialize<XmlDocument>(test);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's throwing an error after adding jQuery, but maybe try...

```
JSON.stringify(myjson)
```

...instead of...

```
myjson.toJSONString()
```

I'm using this with jQuery without issue, but note, I'm using json2.js from www.json.org.  I can't tell if that's what you're using or not.